# Eclipse C/C++ Console is blank after compiling and running OpenCV 3.2.0 code

Tags: c++, eclipse, opencv, cmake

After following [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BBamKg5_JKI&ab_channel=AleksandrIvanov),

I have used CMake, built within Eclipse IDE, added includes to "C:\opencv\new_build\install\include", added "C:\opencv\new_build\install\x64\mingw\bin" to library search path, added

libopencv_core320

libopencv_imgcodecs320

libopencv_imgproc320

libopencv_highgui320

used [this simple openCV program](https://github.com/MicrocontrollersAndMore/OpenCV_3_Windows_10_Installation_Tutorial/blob/master/CannyStill.cpp), put image.jpg into my workspace,
ran my code, with no compilation errors.

g++ "-LC:\opencv\new_build\install\x64\mingw\bin" -o CannyStill.exe "src\CannyStill.o" -llibopencv_core320 -llibopencv_imgcodecs320 -llibopencv_imgproc320 -llibopencv_highgui320

13:52:09 Build Finished (took 1s.510ms)

However, nothing appears in my console, it simply stays blank. Images should appear in windows. I am receiving no errors from the IDE so I believe I have linked the libraries correctly.

Does anybody know why this might be happening? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try putting `image.png` into your project folder rather than the workspace. Programs are run from the project folder.

Comment: @Galik I put it in my debug folder and it still doesn't work. In any case the program has a catch where if an image could not be read but this doesn't even print to the console.

Comment: Is the debug folder a sub-folder of the project folder? Usually programs run from the project folder rather than from the debug folder, I would try the project folder. Regarding the output, on the console window's bar there should be a couple of drop-down menus that allow you to select different consoles, you could check that the correct one is selected.

Comment: @Galik when adding to workspace, the image appears in the main directory for the project, like [this](http://imgur.com/a/ivtSV), however, the .exe is inside the Debug folder, the image can be put [there](http://imgur.com/a/Qxxs9) aswell. Both options don't work.

Comment: How are you running the program?

Comment: in reading this it sounds like your exe runs, displays the console, does not display the image windows and waits for your key input...  If you run it through the debugger can you step through the code?  Do the image variables get loaded  with reasonable addresses etc?  Have you tried writing the images to files as they are generated to see if they are valid?

Comment: @WilliamJones I ran it through cmd and it strangely works, it is unable to work within the Eclipse IDE. I have no idea why this is the case.

Comment: @Galik I ran it through cmd and it strangely works, it is unable to work within the Eclipse IDE. I have no idea why this is the case.

Comment: Are you perhaps hitting a break point in the IDE?  That would be a reason it runs from the command prompt but you don't see results from the IDE